# Значение поля PDU-type в протоколе SNMP

Tags: snmp

SNMP служба Windows7  в сообщении тип GetResponse-PDU кодирует байтом `0xa2==10100010`. Откуда взялось это значение? Если я правильно понял [rfc1157 страница 30](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1157.txt)  должен быть `0x02==00000010`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNMP протокол, для передачи данных, использует стандарт [X.690](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690). В состав SNMP сообщения входит **protocol data units**

```
 -- protocol data units

         PDUs ::=
                 CHOICE {
                     get-request
                         GetRequest-PDU,

                     get-next-request
                         GetNextRequest-PDU,

                     get-response
                         GetResponse-PDU,

                     set-request
                         SetRequest-PDU,

                     trap
                         Trap-PDU
                      }
```

Который также должен быть представлен в стандарте X.690. Таким образом байт `0xa2`  следует рассматривать как идентификатор типа переменной в смысле стандарта X.690.

```
0xa2 == 10 1 00010
```

Это означает что переменная имеет класс: **Context-specific**, тип **Constructed** и тег **GetResponse**

Например пакет SNMPv1 :

```
0x30 0x28 //Начало последовательности включающей все сообщение 
0x02 0x01 0x00 //Версия
0x04 0x04 0x74 0x65 0x73 0x74 //Строка comunity == "test"
0xa2 //идентификатор PDU-type
0x1d //длинна PDU-type
0x02 0x01 0x02 //Request ID
0x02 0x01 0x00 //error-status
0x02 0x01 0x00 //error-index
0x30 0x12 //Последовательность содержащая variable bindings 
0x30 0x10 //Последовательность содержащая одну переменную
0x06 0x09 0x2b 0x06 0x01 0x02 0x01 0x19 0x02 0x02 0x00//OID
0x02 0x03 0x1f 0xfd 0xf8//Значение
```